Android app rejected. Your app is uploading users' Installed Application information to ${HTTP_REQUEST} without a prominent disclosure
Have been uploading the app successfully without any issues for years.
Got a rejection response today.

Your app is uploading users' Installed Application information to ${HTTP_REQUEST} without a prominent disclosure.

What does it mean?
The app is not uploading any installed Application information at all.
